How to change spacing between x ticks in bar chat in matplotlib?
I have a bar chart plot similar to the one here (code below):
# data from https://allisonhorst.github.io/palmerpenguins/

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

species = ("Adelie", "Chinstrap", "Gentoo")
penguin_means = {
    'Bill Depth': (18.35, 18.43, 14.98),
    'Bill Length': (38.79, 48.83, 47.50),
    'Flipper Length': (189.95, 195.82, 217.19),
}

x = np.arange(len(species))  # the label locations
width = 0.25  # the width of the bars
multiplier = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')

for attribute, measurement in penguin_means.items():
    offset = width * multiplier
    rects = ax.bar(x + offset, measurement, width, label=attribute)
    ax.bar_label(rects, padding=3)
    multiplier += 1

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Length (mm)')
ax.set_title('Penguin attributes by species')
ax.set_xticks(x + width, species)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', ncols=3)
ax.set_ylim(0, 250)

plt.show()

But, nowhere am I able to find how to adjust the spacing between the x ticks.  E.g., if I had more than 3 bars, I would need to adjust the spacing between the x ticks, and even more so if the width of my bars is large.
I've seen the questions How to change spacing between ticks and How to reduce the space between the x-ticks in matplotlib? but those are not for a bar chart.
How do I increase the spacing between x ticks, and hence increase the spacing between groups of bars?  Thank you.

Is this what you are looking for [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575067/how-to-increase-the-space-between-bar-plot-bars]?

I believe the "axis" environment is different than "plt".  So I don't think the solution used in that question is applicable to the ax object shown in my code snippet above (unless you can show me how it is).

The spacing between the x-ticks doesn't need to change.  It's the width of the bars and the numbers of bars relative to the distance between the x-ticks that determine how the groups look like.
The code is easiest when the distance between the ticks stays fixed at 1 unit.  In the example below, a gap of 0.2 x units is chosen, while the remaining 0.8 is evenly divided between the bars in a group.  To keep the tick marks at the integer positions, the half of 0.8 is subtracted from the offset. That way, the groups keep nicely centered around these integer positions.
By default, ax.bar() aligns the center of each bar to the indicated x positions. To make the position easier to control when multiple bars are involved, align='edge' will position the bars via their left edge.
To make the code more "pythonic", the multiplier can be obtained from the enumeration of the penguin_means. This avoids mistakes and is simpler than having to initialize and increment a counter.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

species = ("Adelie", "Chinstrap", "Gentoo")
penguin_means = {
    'Bill Depth': (18.35, 18.43, 14.98),
    'Bill Length': (38.79, 48.83, 47.50),
    'Flipper Length': (189.95, 195.82, 217.19),
}

x = np.arange(len(species))  # the label locations
num_in_group = len(penguin_means)
gap = 0.2
width = (1 - gap) / num_in_group  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')

for multiplier, (attribute, measurement) in enumerate(penguin_means.items()):
    offset = width * multiplier - (1 - gap) / 2
    rects = ax.bar(x + offset, measurement, width, align='edge', label=attribute)
    ax.bar_label(rects, padding=3)

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Length (mm)')
ax.set_title('Penguin attributes by species')
ax.set_xticks(x, species)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', ncols=3)
ax.set_ylim(0, 250)

plt.show()

